# What's the best practice with Kentico 8.2 and LESS files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, kentico

I'm working on a new site within Kentico, and the plan is a combination of portal and code via Visual Studio. I had originally thought i would use SASS, but read and implemented the LESS module.

So, when i create a new CSS in the portal, i can now select LESS as the language. When i do this, i don't see any new files with the appropriate App_Theme folder, nor do i see any LESS files in the CSS portal.

The main goal is the use the Bootstrap grid system, with some custom variables and mixins, as well as other custom elements, but i'm stumped on what i thought would be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for v9, but should work for v8 as well (maybe with some minor mods) but should get you what your looking for with being able to edit/view the items in the Kentico UI.

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Registering+CSS+preprocessors

Comment: I think that's exactly what @MJhandy did. If I understand the question correctly, he's trying to use bootstrap (that's stored in a filesystem) in combination with a CSS stored in a DB.

Comment: I can create mutple LESS css files in portal, but there doesn't seem to be a way to import multiple LESS files. 

So I can't set up LESS variables or mixins and use them else where. Is this correct?

Comment: I think i have it. @import worked, as long as the code name didn't have any hyphens.

My test has three imports (bootstrap, colours as variables, and an initial mixin). When i switch to Plain CSS preview, i see the full CSS.

Comment: @MJhandy you can use this macro to import multiple stylesheets in your one stylesheet. `{% CSS["StyleSheetCodeName"] %}`

Comment: I've read that, but assumed it would only work with css, not less. For example, I'vegot a less file for mixins, another for variables. Currently, i'm using @import "fileName"; to include these. It's a bit different that what i'm used to, but it's working well. Thanks!